# PHP For Loop Not Reading File

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, directory, wamp

So I have a website that I'm making along with a course, and I ran into a problem.

I am trying to read the contents of a .txt file into a for loop to print the contents into a form option selection.

Here's the `for` loop:

```
<p>
City Where You Want to Reside:<br />
<select name="city" size="1">
    <option value="-">-</option>

<?php
    $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

    $filename = $DOCUMENT_ROOT.'data'.'cities.txt';

    $lines_in_file = count(file($filename));

    //print "<br>lines: ".$lines_in_file;

    $fp = fopen($filename, 'r');   //opens the file for reading

    $bool = file_exists($filename);

    if ($bool == true)
    {
        for ($ii = 1; $ii <= $lines_in_file; $ii++)
        {
            $line = fgets($fp);
            $file_city = trim($line);

            print '<option value="'.$file_city.'">'.$ii.':'.$file_city.'</option>';
        }

        fclose($fp);
    }
?>

</select>
```

The *cities.txt* file has this:

```
Chicago
Detroit
Toronto
Los Angeles
```

I am getting nothing back from the options besides the "-". I think that the problem might be that it cannot find the file, because the form just outputs the "-" option, and the file_exists function is not finding the file, and cancels the operation.

When I "view page source" it says this where the code for the city selection should be:

```
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' 

cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: file(C:/wamp64/wwwwww\datacities.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\assignment_3.php on line <i>50</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0101</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>408544</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\assignment_3.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\assignment_3.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0101</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>408600</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.file' target='_new'>file</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\assignment_3.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\assignment_3.php<b>:</b>50</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\wamp64\www\assignment_3.php on line <i>50</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0101</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>408544</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\assignment_3.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\assignment_3.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: fopen(C:/wamp64/wwwwww\datacities.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\assignment_3.php on line <i>54</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0101</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>408544</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\assignment_3.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\assignment_3.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0118</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>409328</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.fopen' target='_new'>fopen</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\assignment_3.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\assignment_3.php<b>:</b>54</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

I did notice the `Warning: file(C:/wamp64/wwwwww\datacities.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\assignment_3.php on line <i>50</i>` and wondered if the wwwwww might be causing the issue? If so, how do I fix it?

By the way, I am using WAMP to host these files. I am also using Notepad ++ to edit the PHP and .txt files.

Comment: Yes, there's an extra `www` coming from somewhere but not apparent from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text file is in the same directory as the PHP file then just don't use a path.  If the file is in a `data` sub-directory for example, use what is below. All of the code can be done with the following:

```
$lines = file('data/cities.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach($lines as $ii => $file_city) {
    echo '<option value="'.$file_city.'">'.($ii+1).':'.$file_city.'</option>';
}
```

Regardless of how you do it, you don't want to load the file with `file` and then open it and read it line by line.  Just read each line until the end of file:

```
$ii = 1;
if($fp = fopen('data/cities.txt', 'r')) {
    while($line = fgets($fp)) {
        $file_city = trim($line);
        echo '<option value="'.$file_city.'">'.$ii.':'.$file_city.'</option>';
        $ii++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvote because OP's incessant variable declarations are infuriating.

Comment: Doh!  I just broke it apart to get rid of scrollbar :-(

Comment: I'm sorry about the variable declarations, MonkeyZeus how can I make them better? I'm willing to go back and edit my question. Also, I didn't write this code, it is actually the instructor's code that was broken as well, which may point to me having a faulty folder hierarchy. Also, the cities.txt file is in a folder called "data" under C:\wamp64\www\data, so the cities.txt file is not on the same level of the PHP file. The PHP file is in the C:\wamp64\www.

EDIT: The variables are being declared so much because in the next section, he goes over functions. That cuts down on the variables.

Comment: Yahoo! The second part fixed it! I just had to add the data\ to the cities.txt to get it to go to the right file. Quick question, why do you think that the instructor had the document root variable with all of the confusing " 'data'.'cities.txt' " stuff if this works just as good? I'm sorry for any inconvenience that I might have caused due to lack of formatting or anything else.